# MariaDB server isn't rejoining as slave after being down

Tags: mysql, mariadb, failover, maxscale, gtid

I was testing a few failover cases & initially this was my setup

```
maxctrl list servers
┌─────────┬────────────────┬──────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────┐
│ Server  │ Address        │ Port │ Connections │ State           │ GTID       │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┤
│ server1 │ XXX.XXX.XX.XXX │ 3306 │ 0           │ Slave, Running  │ 0-1-853336 │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┤
│ server2 │ XXX.XXX.XX.XXX │ 3306 │ 0           │ Master, Running │ 0-1-853336 │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┤
│ server3 │ XXX.XXX.XX.XXX │ 3306 │ 0           │ Slave, Running  │ 0-1-853336 │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┤
│ server4 │ XXX.XXX.XX.XXX │ 3307 │ 0           │ Slave, Running  │ 0-1-853336 │
└─────────┴────────────────┴──────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┘
```

I shut down Master (server2) & Slave (server1) & started them again manually, so this became the setup -

```
maxctrl list servers
┌─────────┬────────────────┬──────┬─────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────┐
│ Server  │ Address        │ Port │ Connections │ State           │ GTID       │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┤
│ server1 │ XXX.XXX.XX.XXX │ 3306 │ 0           │ Running         │ 0-1-853336 │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┤
│ server2 │ XXX.XXX.XX.XXX │ 3306 │ 0           │ Running         │ 0-1-853336 │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┤
│ server3 │ XXX.XXX.XX.XXX │ 3306 │ 0           │ Master, Running │ 0-1-853336 │
├─────────┼────────────────┼──────┼─────────────┼─────────────────┼────────────┤
│ server4 │ XXX.XXX.XX.XXX │ 3307 │ 0           │ Slave, Running  │ 0-1-853336 │
└─────────┴────────────────┴──────┴─────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Now, since `auto_failover=true` & `auto_rejoin=true`, server1 & server2 should rejoin as slaves but they continue to show status as running. I even tried manually rejoining them the command `maxctrl call command mariadbmon rejoin DatabaseMonitor server1` but it's showing this error -

```
Error: Server at 127.0.0.1:8989 responded with status code 403 to `POST maxscale/modules/mariadbmon/rejoin?DatabaseMonitor&server1`:{
    "errors": [
        {
            "detail": "'server1' cannot replicate from master server 'server3': gtid_current_pos of 'server1' (0-1-853336) is incompatible with gtid_binlog_pos of 'server3' (0-200-3)."
        }
    ]
```

I'm sure I'm missing out something on GTID replication but I can't understand why. Can anyone tell what's happening or how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `log_slave_updates` enabled on all your database nodes: this is required for both failover and switchover to work as the binlog events must be available on all nodes.

This might also be related to [this bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-3971) which describes a similar situation: if no new transactions occur between the failover from one node to another, the rejoining nodes cannot join as the `gtid_binlog_pos` of new the master server is not compatible with the `gtid_current_pos` of the old master server, exactly as the error message describes.

If you run a command that creates a binlog event (e.g. `FLUSH LOGS`) on the new master server, the rejoin should work after that.